# What are the good practice for error handling for Rails API

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on this website where using Ruby on Rails as the back end API, for such purpose, what are the good practices for error handling in the back end?
For example, if the response is 'not found', how can I return a `json` data indicating such messages robustly?

EDIT:

Adding example and more background info for clarification

For example, in the backend, if I have

```
def top_photos
  user = User.find params[:user_id]
  photos = user.photos.order(created_at: :desc)
                             .limit(10)
  render json: user, status: 200
end
```

if there are any errors in the process, like the user with the given `user_id` cannot be found,
what a a good practice to return a json format data to the front end so that the error could be handled in the frontend?

A little more background: there are already 50+ controllers existing in the website, what can I so that the change is minimal and adaptive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that the following is your code, a status can be rendered in every

```
user = {
  name: "Tang",
  id: 40
}
render :json => user.to_json, :status => :ok
```

Popular status codes, check out [HTTP Status Codes and RESTful API crafting](http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2012/08/http-status-codes-and-restful-api-crafting/):

```
200 :ok
201 :created
202 :accepted
400 :bad_request
401 :unauthorized
403 :forbidden
500 :internal_server_error
```

---

#### For Handling General Errors

If you have a custom route for your apis you may put this in your "ApplicationController" (or in the main controller of your namespace, usually the ApiController):

```
 # CUSTOM EXCEPTION HANDLING
  rescue_from StandardError do |e|
    error(e)
  end

  def routing_error
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(params[:path])
  end

  protected

  def error(e)
    #render :template => "#{Rails::root}/public/404.html"
    if env["ORIGINAL_FULLPATH"] =~ /^\/api/
    error_info = {
      :error => "internal-server-error",
      :exception => "#{e.class.name} : #{e.message}",
    }
    error_info[:trace] = e.backtrace[0,10] if Rails.env.development?
    render :json => error_info.to_json, :status => 500
    else
      #render :text => "500 Internal Server Error", :status => 500 # You can render your own template here
      raise e
    end
  end
```